# Rails form helper and RESTful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, html-helper

I have a form partial current setup like this to make new blog posts

```
<% form_for([@current_user, @post])  do |f| %>
```

This works great when editing a post, but when creating a new post I get the following error:

```
undefined method `user_posts_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x6158104>
```

My routes are setup as follows:

```
map.resources :user do |user|
 user.resources :post
end
```

Is there a better way to setup my partial to handle both new posts and editing current posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map.resources :user do |user|
  user.resources :posts
end
```

pluralize your model names in routes declaration. as you can see it says resourc-**es**, so you must use user-**s** and post-**s** too.

Controllers should be named UsersController and PostsController

Models should be named User and Post.

if above example still does not work for you, try a this one

```
map.resources :users do |u|
  u.resources :posts
end
```

Comment: You are awesome, one of rails nuances. Thanks!